# How to generate a random list of fixed length of values from given range?

Tags: python, random, list, sample

How to generate a random (but unique and sorted) list of a fixed given length out of numbers of a given range in Python?

Something like that:

```
>>> list_length = 4
>>> values_range = [1, 30]
>>> random_list(list_length, values_range)

[1, 6, 17, 29]

>>> random_list(list_length, values_range)

[5, 6, 22, 24]

>>> random_list(3, [0, 11])

[0, 7, 10]
```

Comment: With or without duplication? (i.e. is `[1,4,7,1]` allowed as output?)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A random sample like this returns list of unique items of sequence.  Don't confuse this with random integers in the range.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(30), 4)
[3, 1, 21, 19]
```

Comment: Thank you!

I'd add assigning result to a variable and doing variable.sort() on it to match example above, but I did not ask for it explicitly, so, your solution is the best.

Answer (score 16):

A combination of [random.randrange](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) and list comprehension would work.

```
import random
[random.randrange(1, 10) for _ in range(0, 4)]
```

Comment: You should consider using the _ (underscore) variable instead of count.

Comment: @Soravux: Agree. Changed. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it better to use the _ (underscore)?

Comment: @Norfeldt It signifies a temporary variable that's not used.

Comment: @Norfeldt cos its coooool :P

Answer (score 1):

```
import random


def simplest(list_length):
    core_items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    random.shuffle(core_items)
    return core_items[0:list_length]

def full_random(list_length):
    core_items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    result = []
    for i in range(list_length):
        result.append(random.choice(core_items))
    return result
```

Comment: This works if you don't want duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using random.choices() if you want to sample with replacement.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choices(range(15), k=3)
[24, 29, 17]
```